# Yehareg v'al ya'avor – what about retroactively?

Tags: halacha, arayot, martyr, conditional-stipulation

Based on [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71274/11532) and [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17680/11532).

If someone has possibly committed one of the Big Three sins, and the only way to get out of it retroactively is to commit suicide, is suicide allowed?  Is it required?

An example of this would be if a man marries a woman on condition that she's alive in a week, and then she has an affair within that week.  Can she kill herself?  Is she *required* to kill herself?

Comment: It wouldn't be better to force an afkainhu situation?

Comment: @DoubleAA let's say she's locked in a room 5 minutes before shkiah of the 7th day

Comment: That would still depend on oneis for tnai, ketubbot ~3

Comment: Also Tosfot to gittin 33 about that. This is like the classic case of שמא יחפה

Comment: Can’t he have his vow nullified by three men? Or can’t he claim Mekach Ta’us based on the fact that he thought she wasn’t (going to) have[ing] an affair?

Comment: @Loani what vow?  And it's nolad (or could be).

Comment: His promise to marry her

Comment: @Loani he already married her.

Comment: Not sure this is true, but an interesting side point- Perhaps she can't kill herself, because it's not definite that she committed eishes ish; Maybe she'll die before the time is up anyways, and not have committed it at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yehareg v'al ya'avor – what about after?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71274/yehareg-val-yaavor-what-about-after)

Comment: @kouty no.  My question is different because killing herself would retroactively prevent the sin.

Comment: Right. Maybe good to make this appearent in the title