# What would a Jew be willing to die for?

Tags: death, martyr

What things would a Jew be willing to die for? Answers with a textual basis would be preferred.

Comment: https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah296/

Comment: @Danno Thanks! For other people who might find this question, if you have time, could you make this into an answer?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14477/759

Comment: @DoubleAA That's more specific... Although, if that _is_ the only set of reasons...

Comment: The older question is both more and less specific. The older question asks whether we die for things, and this asks *what* we die for. But the older question asks whether we *may* die for things and this asks about *willingness* (which I assume means propriety). Nonetheless, since the questions overlap so much and the older question has a good answer that directly addresses this question, I think we should close this one as a duplicate. I mean, your curiosity is satisfied, isn't it, wizzwizz4? (cc @DoubleAA)

Comment: @msh210 I suppose most if not all of those answers could be reworded to fit here... Yes, I think that question has sufficient answers. Could you flag this as duplicate please? (cc @DoubleAA)